# Decision Split done button greyed out

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am having troubling configuring a Decision Split in a journey with SF Campaign Member object as the entry event. The entry source includes the campaign ID via `CampaignMember:Campaign:Id`.

In the Decision Split, I added a attribute-to-attribute comparison to match the campaign ID in the Journey Data and Contact Data
[image: Decision Split Filter]

I am not sure what I didn't wrong, but the `Done` button is greyed out, so I can't save the Decision Split.
[image: Greyed out Done]

Have you experienced this before? What did I do incorrectly?

I refrain from doing it but I know a workaround would be linking a DE to Attribute Group keeping the campaign status and run automation on schedule.

Comment: Is one of your attribute to attribute field nullable? In that case, a popup states "Nullable fields cannot be compared. One of these two fields is nullable.", but allows you to save the comparison anyway, but not to create the split (greyed "Done")

Comment: Have you tested the decision split functionality with Status equals In Progress alone?  We've not found the need for your first filter criteria the campaign member ID included in the Journey entry criteria will make the link to the synched DE without it.

Comment: @FrançoisPerret the values aren't nullable. `Id` is a PK of the Campaign synchronised DE while `CampaignMember:Id` is also not nullable in the journey DE.

Comment: @TimZ - yes, the split with Status alone, but Lead to Campaign is a 1-to-many relationship, hence it needs to add the first filter criteria with campaign ID.  In fact, SFMC promoted a warning message at the top after I added Status in: "At least one attribute in this filter criteria could produce multiple matching values. By default, Journey Builder uses the first matching value. You can use attribute-to-attribute comparison to determine the right match."

Comment: @FrançoisPerret, I am sorry. I have misread the DE field name and can confirmed that the `CampaignMember:Campaign:Id` ID is the field and was indeed a nullable value in the journey DE. I tried to updated the field to "is required" but I still get the "Nullable field cannot be compared" warning. More research showed this is an known issue - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KRe8QAG

Comment: @Eliott, so please consider accepting the following answer

Comment: @Eliott, my bad the use case I'm familiar with is pulling in campaignmember status not campaign.  Thanks for clarifying as it helped me wrap my arm around the one to many and helped us validate when it's 1to1 vs 1tomany.  So thank you for sharing.

Comment: @Elliot, have you tried creating a DE via a query to populate the values needed to make the match to your campaign member to the Campaign?  That's the goal here, to move the campaign member subscriber if their corresponding Campaign status is "In Progress"?  Should be a pretty easy query (1) SELECT Status (2) FROM campaign synched DE (3) Where campaign ID = 'campaign ID to filter'. 

Create a custom attribute in Data Designer (Contact Builder) and you should be good to go.

Comment: @TimZ this is what I would do now, but the plan was to use SF data to achieve near real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute to Attribute comparaison should be done between **non-nullable** fields.

You will be able to save the comparison if not (which can be misleading), but not to activate the decision split, hence the greyed button.